# The "smallest" and "Largest" finitely generated infinite group.

Tags: group-theory

The smallest finite group that can be generated by $n$ elements and cannot be generated by any less than $n$ elements is a product of $n$ cyclic groups of order $2$.

(a) Is there a largest finitely generated infinite group that can be generated by $n$ elements but not by more than $n$ elements? 
Largest in the sense that if you remove or change any relation between the generators you end up with a group that can be generated by more than $n$ elements.

**ADDED**: (a) is not really a question since any infinite group $G$ can be infinitely generated $<G>$.  I'm stupid.

(b) Is there a smallest finitely generated infinite group generated by $n$ elements yet cannot be generated by less than $n$ elements? Smallest in the sense that any extra relation imposed on the group's generators will result in a finite group (or an infinite group generated by less than $n$ elements).

Comment: @PVAL see my edit.

Comment: Isn't every finite Symmetric Group generated by 2 elements? A transposition and an n-cycle. Therefore, there does not exist a largest group generated by only 2 generators?

Comment: @JoshB. Thank you for making the question more precise.

Comment: Concerning the question about largest finitely generated infinite group I remark that a removal or a change of a relation between generators does not increase the number of generators of the group.

Comment: Concerning the question about smallest finitely generated infinite group I remark that it seems that each such simple group is minimal according to your definition. There are many such groups (see pp. [189-190](http://books.google.com.ua/books?id=aiPVBygHi_oC&pg=PA189&hl=ru&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=3#v=onepage&q&f=false) of “Combinatorial group theory” by Roger C. Lyndon and Paul E. Schupp). Moreover, every countable group can be embedded in a six-generator simple group.

Comment: @AlexRavsky Isn't the braid group an example of finitely generated group that cannot be infinitely generated, yet if you remove all the relations it becomes free and thus can be infinitely generated?

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding something and now I don’t remember an exact definition of the braid group, but  
each infinite group $G$ can be infinitely generated provided we take $G$ as the set of its generators, isn’t it?

Comment: @AlexRavsky Aha! i see now what confused me. Thanks for clarifying this! regarding your statenemt that any simple group is minimal could you explain?

Comment: It seems the following. Suppose that we have a group $G$ generated by its subset $A$ and the set of relations $R$. If we add some extra relations $R_1$ to the set $R$ then the group $G’$ generated by the set $A$ with the family $R’=R\cup R_1$ of relations will be a quotient $G/N$ of the group $G$ with respect to its normal subgroup $N$. If $N$ is the unit subgroup, then all relations of the set $R_1$ are corollaries of  the set $R$ of relations, so this case is trivial.

Comment: But if $G$ is a simple group then each its normal non-unit subgroup $N$ coincides with $G$, so in this case $G’=G/G$ is the unit (that is a finite) group.

Answer (score 2):

Question (b) is equivalent to asking if there exists a group which is generated by $n$ elements (and no fewer) such that every non-trivial normal subgroup has finite index.

You can always add a group relation which is already implied by the group axioms or existing relations without changing your group. When you impose a non-trivial relation, you are quotienting by the normal closure of all of those elements which satisfy that relation.

There do exist such groups. The easiest example is $\Bbb Z$. All of its nontrivial quotients are finite, and it cannot be generated by 0 elements. Another example is the infinite dihedral group $D_\infty$ which requires 2 generators. In this group all normal subgroups have finite index, but there are still subgroups with infinite index. Also, any finitely-generated infinite simple group satisfies this requirement as mentioned in the comments. If we take a finite generating set, we can reduce it to a minimal generating set. We can then consider the collection of all minimal generating sets and then set $n$ to be the minimum of those cardinalities.

If you only want to consider quotients which have fewer generators than the original group, that seems to be a difficult question. In finitely-generated non-abelian groups, you can have minimal generating sets of different cardinality. And you can even have subgroups which require more generators than the whole group itself does.